# SSL does not work in Oracle Weblogic Server

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic

I configured all SSL settings in Weblogic Server Administration Console. SSL port is 7102, I also used demo truststore, keystore, which was installed with OES.

So it doesn't work. When I open https(no urls)site.ru:7102 I get http 404 error.
I check listening ports with netstat on the server and there is not any process which listen port 7102. When I try edit SSL port in Weblogic Server Administration Console nothing happens. I also tried change common "Listen Port" and "Activate Changes" but nothing happens, Weblogic Server still works on old port - 7101.
When I use OES Client config util, which connect with server throw SSL I get this exception:

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:407)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at oracle.security.oes.enroll.EnrollmentClient.enroll(EnrollmentClient.java:135)
    at oracle.security.oes.enroll.EnrollmentClient.main(EnrollmentClient.java:478)
    at oracle.security.oes.tools.EnrollmentTool.doEnroll(EnrollmentTool.java:103)
    at oracle.security.oes.tools.SMConfigTool.doEnrollment(SMConfigTool.java:1192)
    at oracle.security.oes.tools.SMConfigTool.run(SMConfigTool.java:617)
    at oracle.security.oes.tools.SMConfigTool.main(SMConfigTool.java:546)
Connection refused: connect
```

Tell me, please, what could be the reason. What should I do to run SSL listening on Weblogic?

Comment: So you have `SSL Listen Port Enabled` checked for your server in the admin console? Check that and uncheck `Listen Port Enabled` and then activate changes. When you start your server you should see "Listening on port 7102" in the log

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens. The server stil listen 7101 port. Maybe I have to do something after "Activate Changes"?

Comment: Server is running on the virtual machine. We are using 3proxy for routing. I think maybe it will be usefull information.

Comment: It shouldn't matter that you are running on a virtual machine, all of my servers are. Stop your server and edit your `<domain home>/config/config.xml` file. Find your server and set `<listen-port-enabled>false</listen-port-enabled>` and `<two-way-ssl-enabled>true</two-way-ssl-enabled>` then restart your server.

Comment: Yes, it was checked. I just restarted the server manually and SSL worked. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try three options...

1. Take a backup of config.xml and edit it by placing the ssl port make sure ssl port enabled tag is true
2. Goto admin console there also change the ssl port as per your requirement what you put in the config.xml

3.Make sure you opened that port in firewall

Goto Run -> wf.msc -> inbound connection -> new rule -> port -> finish

Restart all the nodes (Both admin and managed)